# "since" and the present progressive?

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous

I am wondering about the use of a since-phrase and the present progressive like the following:

How is he bearing up since the accident?

Normally, the since-phrase triggers the perfect aspect. Why is it not so in this case?

DO you think this interchangeability can be extended to "I am living here since 1995"?

Comment: You could perfectly well ask "How has he been bearing up since the accident?"

Comment: Could you say "I am living here since 1998" in place of "I have been living here since 1998"?

Comment: *"How is he bearing up since the accident?"* is acceptable. *"I am living here since 1998"* is not. By far the safest thing to do is to use a perfect aspect with *since* — you won't be wrong.

Comment: Do you know why one is right and the other is wrong?

Comment: I dont think it is related to 'since'. The first sentence is about a point in time after the accident, the second is about duration.

Comment: Good question. I'd like to see one of the close-voters suggest a reference covering 'situations where the present continuous may be used before _since_'. I think you've found a rare example; 'How is he doing since ...' works too. They're probably colloquialisms for the standard form 'How has he been doing ...?' (though the expression itself is colloquial).

Answer (score 1):

This example "how is he bearing up since the accident?" should be thought of as a question "How is he bearing up?"  with an afterthought as a modifier "since the accident."  As a single sentence -- especially in writing -- you would always use the perfect "How has he been bearing up since the accident?"